# Is there a Stack Exchange meta?

Tags: support, stackexchange

Is there is a *Stack Exchange* meta: a meta that applies to the **entire** Stack Exchange network and allows for users from all sub-sites to contribute feedback that could be applied to the entire network?

Comment: Check the footer. Look for "other"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's http://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: this answer cracks me up. [i did this once](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137273/52934), and am rather ashamed of the number of votes it received, but i still chuckle when i look at it.

Comment: @mikeserv but votes on meta do not count for reputation, do they?

Comment: @jimmij - beats me. this answer is still funny as hell.